# How to put other elements with listview in an activity?

Tags: android, listview

I want to have a header containing the logo. And then a list view. But i am struggling to get both of them in a screen. Either i get only header or only Listview. Could anyone please shed some light here. Here are my files.

### // Grammar_sections.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grammar_sections);
   Intent i = getIntent();

    module_id =i.getStringExtra("module_id");

    TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getBaseContext());        
    mDbHelper.open();

    ArrayList<String> testdata = mDbHelper.getAllSections(module_id);

    for(String t : testdata )
    {
        //Log.d("out", t.toString());
    }

    mDbHelper.close();


    m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    if(m_listview != null)
    {
        Log.i("check","yup");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("check","nope");
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.grammar_sections , R.id.list_item, testdata);

     m_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### grammar_sections.xml

```
  // grammar_sections.xml

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<!--  Header  Starts-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">
            <!-- Logo Start-->
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo_icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>


            <!-- Logo Ends -->
       </LinearLayout>
   <!--  Header Ends -->



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="16dip"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    />

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
     />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried putting the header above the xml which contains the <listview>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code,

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.grammar_sections , R.id.list_item, testdata);
```

You are passing same **grammar_sections.xml** file to your **ArrayAdapter**. So I think its the problem, Instead make a different xml layout file which contains list items and pass this xml layout file to **ArrayAdapter** constructor..

Comment: But the image is a child in Linear Layout. So it will not matter. And as a matter of fact i need it to be fill_parent for the logo to be shown properly.

Actually what i am getting from this code is a list containing all the correct values. But all of them has the header right at the top of them. So i am getting 4 values and 5 headers.

Comment: What about the list view? Does it have to be in the same activity as the one we mention in Array Adapter?

Comment: No. just ListItem means.. TextView, put `TextView` in different xml layout file and pass this xml file to ArrayAdapter's constructor. And ListView remain in same **grammar_sections.xml** file don't change it.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` has the method [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29). As the doc says:

```
Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the list.
```

So simply create your `view` and retrive it throug an `inflater` . Then add it to the `ListView`

Comment: Isnt there another way? Thats too much. And everybody seems to get it by normal method only. Whats the problem with mine? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: the HeaderView could be anything deriving from View. So could a LinearLayout with all your headers

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample xml code that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/header" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/blue_vdark"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can replace the include by a custom `View` or `Layout` or add one below the `ListView`.
Try to compare this code with yours. Also I don't see the `</RelativeLayout>` tag at the end of your xml file.